# Finding the expected value of the cdf?

Tags: self-study, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-function

I have this question on a homework assignment, and I'm not sure how to solve it.

Assume $X \sim \exp(\lambda=2)$, define $Y=F(x)$, where F(x) is the cdf function of $X$. Calculate the expected value of $Y$, i.e., $E(Y)$.

I thought maybe you could use the Law of the Unconscious Statistician and have the integral of $F(x) * f(x)$? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You made a good start.  Why not take the next step and evaluate that integral?

Comment: I wonder what the derivative of $\frac12 (F(x))^2$ equals?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can definitely use [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician). Alternatively, you can use the Probability Integral Transform which says that the CDF of a continuous random variable follows the uniform distribution. You might want to see if you can arrive at the same result using both methods.